# Twitter widget timeline using publish.twitter.com script is not loading in webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-widget, twitter-timeline

When we use https://publish.twitter.com/# to get the script for Twitter timeline and use it in Webview at mobile app, the script simply showing "Tweets by " as a link instead of showing timeline.

Can anyone suggest what is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I just get an answer from Twitter staff. We need to add **https:** to the widgets.js and its working fine for me.

```
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```